# Both + as well as

Tags: conjunctions, as

I have come across this structure:

> You will find both good as well as bad people in the world.

My question is - Do we need 'as well as' after 'both'? Is this a correct and acceptable structure?

Comment: Well, I dug in further and found this very helpful. This answers your question. http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/11/as-well-as.html

Comment: Why not just use "and" rather than "as well as"?

Answer (score 2):

That sentence has a fairly clumsy construction which makes it difficult interpret- a better structured sentence would be "As well as bad people in the world, you will find that there are also good people" or "You will find that there are both good and bad people in the world". "as well as"  in the case means that its to be expected- the previous information told you that were bad people. "as well as" being long conjunction makes its clumsy splitting the noun (people) from its adjective (good).

Basically its OK as an informal structure and both is required as a regular structure though it doesn't add any meaning.

Comment: "You will find that there are both good and bad people in the world." Does it convey the same meaning?

Comment: Same meaning but slightly different nuance- remember this sentence is in a context where a person experienced people being bad already.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer User2617804 has provided:

- "As well as bad people in the world, you will find that there are also good people"
- "You will find that there are both good and bad people in the world"

Are better structured sentences.

I, myself, recommend you look at these examples. Much depends on what meaning you wish to imply!

- You will find that besides bad people there are also good people in the world.
- You will find that there are good people as well as bad people in the world.
- You will find that in the world there are good people and bad people as well.
- You will find that in addition to bad people there are also good people in the world.
- You will find that there are not only bad people but also good people in the world.

Comment: I'm a little unsure about whether "in addition" is a good choice but I think it can exist as one.